# Do I need a newer Mac if I want to continue to use Xcode with my iPhone?

Tags: macos, ios, xcode

Recently I updated my iPhone 6s to iOS 12.2.

When I went to compile my app, Xcode told me it needed to be upgraded to deploy to device running iOS 12.2.

When I went to upgrade Xcode, it told me my OS needed to be upgraded to macOS Mojave.

When I went to upgrade my Mid 2010 MacBook Pro to Mojave, App Store said “Nah uh, your computer is too old”.

I tried to restore my iPhone to 12.1.4 from the .ipsw, and iTunes says Apple says “Uh um, nope; I decline to authorize…”

Am I separated from my app and data until I pony up for a newer Mac?

Answer (score 4):

Your computer is too old to be officially supported on macOS Mojave, I'm afraid. Also it is not possible to downgrade an iPhone to an older iOS version, unless you have saved certain information before you did the upgrade (which you didn't do).

However there are two unsupported methods of running macOS Mojave anyways, which will enable you to install Xcode 10.2 and develop for iOS 12.

The first option is to use the Mojave Patcher third party utility found here:

http://dosdude1.com/mojave/

It essentially patches a Mojave installation package to be able to run on older, otherwise unsupported hardware.

The other option is to use a virtualisation system such as VMware Fusion or Parallels Desktop and run Mojave inside a virtual machine.

Comment: Not sure how capable OP's 2010 MacBook Pro is, to run macOS Mojave and Xcode 10.2 atop within a virtualizer!

Comment: It is fully capable of doing that - why wouldn't it be?

Comment: Might be a little slow, depends on usage of both the VM and the config and usage of the Mac. If he has the time possibly worth at least trying.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Turns out your only option is get a newer Mac capable of running macOS Mojave.

Your MacBook Pro can't upgrade past macOS High Sierra 10.13.6. Xcode 10.2 requires macOS Mojave 10.14.3 or later to run.

Apple has stopped signing all iOS releases prior to iOS 12.2, thus it is no longer possible to downgrade your iPhone.

Comment: Honestly probably the best bet, unless your money situation is prohibitively low. Heck even a used/newer Mac might be a good idea. Failing all of that using Mojave in a VM or using a Mojave patcher might be viable. But those latter options *might* end up being a bit slow.

Comment: Ofcourse a 9 year old Mac is going to be slower than a new one. But is it going to be significantly slower than running the same programs on High Sierra? - I think the answer is no.